# How to modify history as facebook's photo viewer does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, pushstate, html5-history

I have a popup modal on my website similar to facebook's photo viewer. When the modal is opened, it is displaying content from another page and I want to change the address bar value and history to show this.

There is a dropdown in the modal that changes the content in the modal to that of a different page. When this happens, I once again want to change the address bar value and history to show the page was changed.

**Essentially, I want to exactly replicate the behavior of facebook's photo viewer**, which you can try out by:

1. [Clicking on this link](https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow/timeline)
2. Clicking on `Photos`
3. Clicking on a photo on the page
4. Click the right or left arrows (or use your keyboard arrow keys) to change iamges
5. a) click the back and forward history buttons in your browser
6. b) click out of the photo viewer

I tried to create a JSFiddle to show where I am at with this, but JSFiddle apparently does not allow the history to be manipulated. As such, I've put [my code online here](http://www.pricewombat.com/history/), and which [you can download from here](http://www.pricewombat.com/history.zip).

---

A few key points:

- Start by viewing the index page, then use the link to go to the test page
- When the modal is closed, pressing the back button should **not** reopen the modal, but instead should take you back to the index page.
- After closing the modal, pressing the forward button should reopen the modal in it's original state as facebook's photo viewer does
- In my production code, the full URL will be changed instead of adding/changing a variable in the URL as shown in the demo code

Comment: what about `replaceState`?

Comment: You've read the page? Did you miss the [`popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_popstate_event)?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Maybe I read too fast, but it looked to me like `popstate` is an event you catch, not a function you call to remove an item from history.

Comment: @Nate exactly, it catch when the history is change. So you use this event to prevent the reloading of the page when doing `.back()`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon How would you prevent the page from reloading from inside the event handler?

Comment: @Nate actually, forget everything i said, `window.history.back()` shouldn't reload the page if you did use `pushState`. You must have a problem somewhere else. Test it in the console. Input `window.history.pushState({}, "page 2", "bar.html");`, the url will change, then `window.history.back();` the url will be back to the current one without reloading.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I thought we had it, but look at my most recent edit.

Comment: @Nate Ok, that is where `popstate` come in handy. You need to check when that event is trigger if the page is `mysite.com/anotherpage`, in case it **isn't**, you have to close the pop up.

Comment: I asked the same question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/28561561/104380

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use history API, and specifically you have to use `history.pushState()` [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

So when a user opens the modal you can do something :

```
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "image\id.html");
```

Where : stateObj is the object that you pass through history, page 2 is the title and the last parameter is the URL you want to modify.

After you've done so you have to use on [popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) as the browser Back and Forward buttons won't reload the page.

Comment: Yes, I've tried various things with the history functions, but can't seem to replicate facebook's behavior. The main problem I've had is when closing the modal, I want the back button to make the browser go back to the previous page instead of re-opening the modal, but I can't figure out how to do this. Please see the demo I posted along with looking at facebook's behavior. +1 though.

Comment: @Nate when you close the window don't do a pushState as it does a new insertion on history, do a window.history.back() and check out when you open the modal window.history.length should increase +1 and when you close it should decrease -1 not keep increasing.

Comment: This answers half the question. when you are closing the modal photo viewer, all the pushed states are removed. how do they do that?

Comment: @vsync just call window.history.back();

Comment: This will refresh the page. they do something like `window.history.go(-N)` but it never gets refreshed. that is the mystery .

Comment: @vsync it wont refresh the page if the previous object on history is placed by push state instead of classic browse post back.

Comment: yeah i just realized it won't :) awesome