# How to create a popup with a different url/page like facebook photos

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to ask how do I make a page but when it opened it was like (Modal_bootstrap). For example, when opening a photo on facebook. When the photo on facebook opened the popup will appear and then the url also changes. How to make like that how?. Please help.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried in order to achieve this yourself? Please include any of your attempted code.

Comment: I am confused. When making such use what language?

Comment: This **[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28461881/2065039)** might be helpful!!

Comment: window.history.pushState http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: Broken link, @GuruprasadRao

Comment: What!! I can load it how come you cannot!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572523/how-to-modify-history-as-facebooks-photo-viewer-does/28461881#28461881

Comment: I mean broken link download page

Comment: The download from the main question is irrelevant, the relevant part is the one @GuruprasadRao linked to.